# removing the forward slash from this re-written url

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I know this may sound silly little bit, but there is no other way to resolve it. I have an issue with the forward slash `/`. I want to remove it from the url because it is kind of making some confusion to the browsers giving trusted or un-trusted urls.

This is the code for the main domain:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ /user [R=301,L]
```

and this is the output of the above code: `https://www.mydomain.com/user/`

**but I want the url redirect to this:**

```
https://www.mydomain.com/user
```

I also want to remove the forward slash from this url :

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:\.\w+|/)$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/end)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /top/right/left/bottom/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/top/right/left/bottom
RewriteRule top/right/left/bottom/(end)(/(./*))?$ $1$2 [R,L]
```

and this is the output of the above code: `https://www.mydomain.com/end/`

**but I want the url redirect to this:**

```
https://www.mydomain.com/end
```

**Last question:** why do I have to write **www.** in my own in some browser like FF or chrome so the redirect make itself to the required url?

**All comments are appreciated**

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's called a forward slash.

Comment: That's a slash, not a backslash.

Comment: Thanks @MikeChristensen. I guess you are right. I will edit the post.

Comment: ok, now I know it is a slash/forward slash... so how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the above rewrites rules are written by me. So optimizing it for URL to not end with a `/` (`https://www.mydomain.com/end`)

Replace the whole(from `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200` to `RewriteRule top/right/left/bottom/(end)(/(./*))?$ $1$2 [R,L]`) thing by this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(end)(?:/(.*))? /top/right/left/bottom/$1/$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^top/right/left/bottom/(end)(/.*)?$ $1$2 [R,L]
```

Remember though if you access with a forward slash like this: `https://www.mydomain.com/end/` the forward slash will not be removed.

If you want the `/` to be removed: Replace the last 2 rules by these:

```
RewriteRule ^(end)(?:/(.+))? /top/right/left/bottom/$1/$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(end)/$ $1 [R,L]   
RewriteRule ^top/right/left/bottom/(end)(/.*)?$ $1$2 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @ThinkingMonkey. Yes, the rules were written by you :) . I'm glad you could pass by and explain some important points about this whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Store the url in a variable and perform `rtrim` to remove trailing slash

```
$redirectURL = rtrim($redirectURL, "/");
```

Comment: Thanks @siva for the answer. However, I'm a noob in these stuff and just started few days ago learning it. Can you give a simple example so I can get the idea and then try to apply that on my .htaccess? appreciated it

Comment: @Digitalsite: thanks. Join into this chat room [http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8269/trailing-slash-issue](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8269/trailing-slash-issue)

Comment: @Digitalsite: Am waiting in chat room.

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice your post. I was trying to access to the room, but couldn't and I don't know why!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8272/discussion-between-digital-site-and-siva-charan)